# Implementing Automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I am building Selenium hybrid framework in java using maven and testng. Because new to automation and my project is similar to e-commerce what things I should take care of or how I should approach. I need guidance about architecture and flow.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about it. There are many blogs and videos online as well as a lot of information on Selenium's website about how to setup and use Selenium.
Here is a really quick guide:

Quick Selenium setup tutorial:
http://seleniumsimplified.com/get-started/

Oficial Selenium documentation:
seleniumhq.org/docs/

Good to have info:
seleniumhq.wordpress.com/

Link Selenium Tests with BrowserStack:
www.browserstack.com/automate/java

Quick intro to POM automation framework:
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/
(you can also take a look at Page Factory automation framework which is preferred by some)

Using Extent Reports:
extentreports.com/docs/versions/2/java/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I often use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse the page and use Selenium to perform the actions on the page.

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a good browser for headless testing.

Also, i've recently been putting my methods in callables for when unexpected things happen like getting logged out.  The callable will poll if the thread is done and while it waits a period of time it checks if the state is something not expected in the linear path.